# Is it possible to store elements of array permanently in VBA in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, variables, vba, store

I wrote macro in Excel that uses dynamic array. Users will add elements to that array.

Is it possible to store elements permanently, so the elements will be available even after workbook was closed?

The trick is that I do not want to store elements on a worksheet and insert them back to array when workbook is open, but to have elements permanently saved in array.

Comment: What is wrong with storing on a sheet?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350388/saving-vba-dictionary-object-in-excel/7350849#7350849 There are some notes.

Comment: Please remember to accept answers that work. There is an arrow icon on the upper left of the answers - you can select it to accept the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of your best bets is to store the array values in a worksheet and mark the worksheet as hidden using VBA.

```
Me.Worksheets("ArrayValuesWorksheet").Visible = False
```

If you use other things like local CSV files, registry, etc then the code will behave differently by simply moving the workbook to different machines and you will lose the ability to have multiple copies of the array.

**Edit** (Excellent suggestion in @Reafidy's comments below)

Comment: Use `Sheets("ArrayValuesWorksheet").Visible = xlVeryHidden`  to prevent the sheet appearing in the unhide list.

Comment: You can also password protect your code and "Very Hidden" sheets by going to Tools/VBA Project Properties/Protection Tab and entering a password.  User will not be able to unhide "Very Hidden" sheets.  P.S.  LOL at Microsoft's term "Very Hidden".  I mean, I get it b/c I've been there...it's just funny to see an Enum with that name.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions guys, but I don't want to store data in the hidden worksheets, as I want to distribute macro as some kind of extension, add-in (I don't know yet) so it will work on any workbook whenever the excel is opened. I think it will not be possible to share macro in this way if there is a hidden worksheet attached. By the way can you advise what is the best way to distribute macro?

Comment: Macro is part of the sheet itself - you cannot distribute a macro without distributing the worksheet. For more info, post a separate question.

Comment: One of the best ways to distribute macros is through an addin.  Worksheets go with the addin.  I suggest you learn more about them before deciding on your solution, see here: [Ozgrid - Addins](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm)

Comment: Also,  the benefit of populating the array to the worksheet is you can also sort and work with the array more easily.  Populating the sheet and back to the array variable in one go its only one line of code each time.  Ditch your mind set about not using a worksheet. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also store an array in a name from the names collection, and this name can be hidden.

```
Names.Add Name:="StoredArray", RefersTo:=myArray, Visible:=False
```

Comment: That will store it as a string not an array.

Comment: Thanks Ronie and Reafidy. It is not a problem if it stores data as a string as I suspect I can the read string back to array. What is interesting for me is when I share this macro as some kind of add-in (extension) will it be possible to save data into names collection?

Comment: This is the answer, it's not hard to read it back from the Named Constant back into an array when initializing.

Comment: Much easier to populate the worksheet and read back form it in one go.  Using named constants, yes it is easy to revert if it is a 1D array- using split.  But it gets more tricky if its 2d, you will have to create multiple loops. `MyArray = [{"A","B","C","D";1,2,3,4;"W","x","Y","Z"}]`

Comment: It does not store it as a string.  Open the name manager with an example.  I created a numeric example very easily.  I can retrieve the values with EVALUATE or [].  No loops at all.  I do not dispute that a worksheet works, but I presented a valid alternative.

Comment: +1 Yes you definitely did provide a valid suggestion. Apologies if I sounded negative towards your post it was not intended. I was just trying to clarify. As far as VBA is concerned it is stored as a string. Add a watch to the MyArray variant and you will see Variant/String when populated from the name. Evaluate is limited to to 255 characters, your array will have to be very small. Incidently - if you put @Reafidy in your comment I get notified of it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly: No, there is no way to store an array that has a lifetime beyond the application in memory - you'll have to save it somewhere.

There are several options available but your best is most likely saving it to a sheet. 'Very hidden' sheets are only visible through VBA code so to the user it's the same thing as the array always being there and active in memory.

Answer (score 0):

To read/write Array in sheet you can use

```
Sub WriteArray()
Dim MyArray As Variant

MyArray = Array("x", "y", "z")

Range("A1:C1").Value = MyArray

End Sub

Sub ReadArray()

Dim MyArray As Variant

MyArray = Range("A1:C1").Value

End Sub
```

After you can use the `Visible` property of sheet to hide as we have responded.

Answer (score 0):

"there is no way..." , >>> yes can do !

some examples : listbox/ComboListBox (on a sheet) = array ...

For 2D variant array : range()=array.

Or store it in a commandbarMenu (those can be made multidimensional)

or whateverthat keeps after reloading workbook...